# Excel 2010 1004 Cannot change this part of Pivot Table Report. But worksheet isn't pivot table.

Tags: excel, runtime-error, excel-2010, pivot-table, vba

I have written code to accept a date range to write to specific cells in a worksheet. The ranges are grabbed from an inputbox, stored in variables, and then the variables are written to cells for display. Another subroutine then filters the data according to the values in those cells. I have several pivot tables on other worksheets in the same workbook but not on the worksheet in question. My code:

```
Public Sub InputDateRange()

Dim dteStart As Date, dteEnd As Date
dteStart = InputBox("Please enter a beginning date" _
    , "Enter Analysis Start Date")
dteEnd = InputBox("Please enter an ending date" _
    , "Enter Analysis End Date")
Debug.Print dteStart, dteEnd
Worksheets(4).Cells(2, 2).Value = dteStart
Worksheets(4).Cells(3, 2).Value = dteEnd
```

This throws a Excel Run-Time Error 1004: "Cannot change this part of a Pivot Table report" on the last line. The first line works fine. The second appears to differ from the first only in the row reference and variable written. The worksheet is unprotected at the time of running this subroutine. There is no Pivot Table present on this worksheet.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Well, as it turns out I had to change the worksheets() property to the exact name of the spreadsheet. It works now.  Does the index for a worksheet start at 0 or 1? If I write worksheets(0) does that return the first worksheet in the collection or would that be worksheets(1)?

Comment: It starts at 1 and goes from left to right, including hidden sheets.